# Typescript - Rearrange specific object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I've arranged object in alphabetical order. I wanna move "Others" at last in dropdown. Is there any way to acheive this?

```js
this.registrationMerchantService.getBusinessCategories().subscribe(response => {
  this.businessCategories = response;
  this.businessCategories.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
});
```

**Json objects**

```js
export const BUSINESS_CATEGORIES: BusinessCategory[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Food & Beverage' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Transportation & Travel' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Fashion' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Leisure' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Digital Content' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Health and Beauty' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Online Shopping' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Telecommunications' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Utilities' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Others' },
  { id: 11, name: 'General' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Insurance' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Services' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Appliances' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Entertainment' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Household Goods & Groceries' },
];
```

**Current result:**
[image]

Is there any idea to move "Others" at last in the dropdown list

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. Try to do it. **If** you get stuck, show your attempt, and people will be happy to help.

Comment: I rearranged BUSINESS_CATEGORIES in alphabetical order. But i wanted to moved only "Others" at last in the dropdown list. I tried almost 4 hours, still couldn't figure out and facing difficulties to acheive this. That's why Im here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sorting the array filtering out "Others" and then add it at the end:

```js
    var categories = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Food & Beverage' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Transportation & Travel' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Fashion' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Leisure' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Digital Content' },
      { id: 6, name: 'Health and Beauty' },
      { id: 7, name: 'Online Shopping' },
      { id: 8, name: 'Telecommunications' },
      { id: 9, name: 'Utilities' },
      { id: 10, name: 'Others' },
      { id: 11, name: 'General' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Insurance' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Services' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Appliances' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Entertainment' },
      { id: 16, name: 'Household Goods & Groceries' },
    ];
    const sorted =   categories.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });

    console.log(
      sorted
      .filter(x=>x.name!=="Others")//remove "Others"
      .concat(sorted.find(x=>x.name==="Others"))//add "Others" at the end
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @HMR :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accepts an ignore list, and you can return a sorting function that takes care of ignoring certain names, by placing them above or below in the list.

You can fiddle with the sorting direction to get the desired result.

```js
var BUSINESS_CATEGORIES = [
  { id: 1,  name: 'Food & Beverage' },
  { id: 2,  name: 'Transportation & Travel' },
  { id: 3,  name: 'Fashion' },
  { id: 4,  name: 'Leisure' },
  { id: 5,  name: 'Digital Content' },
  { id: 6,  name: 'Health and Beauty' },
  { id: 7,  name: 'Online Shopping' },
  { id: 8,  name: 'Telecommunications' },
  { id: 9,  name: 'Utilities' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Others' },
  { id: 11, name: 'General' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Insurance' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Services' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Appliances' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Entertainment' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Household Goods & Groceries' },
];

let categories = this.BUSINESS_CATEGORIES.sort(customSort([ 'Others' ], 1));

console.log(JSON.stringify(categories, null, 2));

function customSort(ignoreList, direction) {
  ignoreList = ignoreList || [];
  direction  = direction  || 1;
  return function(a, b) {
    var aPos = ignoreList.indexOf(a.name);
    var bPos = ignoreList.indexOf(b.name);

    if (bPos > -1) return -1 * direction;
    if (aPos > -1) return 1 * direction;

    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) * direction;
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```